# Phone won't play calls both audio element and speech synthesis

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, html5-audio

In a UWP Javascript app using Visual Studio 2017 I have two pieces of code.
If I execute the first, subsequent calls to the second won't play.  If I execute
the second, subsequent calls to the first won't play.  This is happening on my
Windows Phone.  The desktop behaves normally.  What is happening to the output
on my phone?

update: this is failing on an Acer running version 1703. 
However both work fine on a Nokia Lumia running version 1607.

```
var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello");
window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);  

...

player.src = "ms-appx:///audioo/" + "song.wav";
player.play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this occurs in version 1703 as observed.  It was fixed in version 1709.  It was working in 1607.  Phones running 1703 will experience this weird behavior.